# Adding Custom Header using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a contact form which a user types his/her details including his/her email, the code below works well

```
 $mail             = new PHPMailer();
              $body             = $message;
              $mail->IsHTML(true);
              $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
              $mail->Host       = "smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com";
              $mail->Port       = 587;
              $mail->Username   = "name@domainname.net";
              $mail->ContentType ='text/html';
              $mail->Password   = "password";
              $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
              $mail->SetFrom('name@domainname.net', 'my name',false);
              $mail->Subject    = $subject;

              $mail->MsgHTML($body);
              $mail->IsSMTP();
              $address = $to;
              $mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
              if(!$mail->Send()) {
                  return 0;
              } else {
                    return 1;
             }
```

this code sends a mail and a header "From: name@domainname.net", but i want to show the email the user inputs from the contact form. e.g a user inputs myenquiry@anotherdomain.com, i want the from mail to be "From: myenquiry@anotherdomain.com" in which anotherdomain is not in my domain (i.e yahoo small business)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. That is forging the from address and it will usually cause your messages to fail to be delivered because they will fail SPF checks. This is especially the case with Yahoo who is by far the pickiest ISP to deliver to. Put your own address in `From` (as you are doing now), and add the submitter's address in `reply-to` (see `addReplyTo()` in PHPMailer).

Also you've based your code on an old example, so make sure you are using an up to date example and [the latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).